# How do I read target dependencies from a file?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So, I've got that makefile project that has a **huge** list of object files that need to be compiled.

I already ran into problems on Win32 because the input string is too large. I figured out that instead of passing the files 1-by-1 to the linker, I could read the object files to be linked from a file by passing `@filename` to the linker.

In my makefile: Is there a method how the dependencies could be read out of a file? Something like that:

`main.lib: @dependency_file_name`

where `dependency_file_name` holds the list of needed `.obj` files needed to create the lib.

Please keep in mind, that putting the contents of the file into a variable also doesn't work since I've got that problem with a too long input string also when using the list of dependencies as a variable.

In addition: the method shall be portable (Linux, Win32)

---

**Edit**: currently, the structure of my makefiles is as follows:

```
# slurp in some global settings
include /path/to/global/settings

all: prepare_target mylib cleanup_target

prepare_target:
    # do preparing work (setup temp files etc)

cleanup_target:
    # do cleanup work (delete temp files etc)

mylib: \
    file1.obj \
    file2.obj \
    ... \
    file215.obj

# this file holds the dependencies for each .obj file
include file_with_obj_file_dependencies
```

There are really 215 C files to be compiled into this lib. As I said: when feeding this list to the linker, I need to do it via a file because the string is too large for the command line.

I'm free to change whatever is needed in the makefile: it's generated from a VisualStudio vcxproj and I own the generation templates.

`file_with_obj_dependencies` looks as this:

```
file1.obj: \
    file1.c \
    file1.h \

file2.obj: \
    file2.c \
    file2.h \

... \

file215.obj \
    file215.c \
    file215.h \
```

Comment: Within the makefile, does this list exist as a variable?

Comment: @beta: yes, I could do that

Comment: Can you show us *how* you do it? You must have something in place that determines the list.

Comment: Can you split file1.obj..file50.obj into a dummy static lib, file51.obj..file100.obj into another dummy static lib, etc. and pass the dummy libs to the linker instead of the long list of object files? This would achieve the same goal.

Comment: @chrono: This lib is part of a large project with 60 more libs. All makefiles are generated. I'm looking for a generic way, no special treatment

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seaaew50.aspx perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I tend to use cygwin. It's the closest environment I've found to unix. This makes your Makefiles portable. I haven't come across any limiting command-line length limits. Here is an example with over ¾ of a million command-line arguments:

```
a := 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f

.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo $(foreach A,$a,$(foreach B,$a,$(foreach C,$a,$(foreach D,$a,$(foreach E,$a,$A$B$C$D$E))))) | wc -wc
```

(the `wc` is so that you don't have to wait for the 5,000,000 or so characters to scroll by.)

So, for the limited win32 tools, use bash to write the intermediate *command-line-parameters* file, then pass that to `link.exe` (say) prefixed with an `@`.

Something like:

```
mylib.lib:
    echo $^ >$@-tmp
    link -o $@ @$@-tmp
```

(Are you sure you need the intermediate file? 215 source files doesn't seem too onerous.)